# Getting a user by id in JHipster

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I have an issue with this. Some of the entities I created have a relationship with the User table. As such, they contain a field called userId. On the page on which I'm detailing them, I'd wish to show the User's username, not his ID(for example a review page, it would look better if it said "post by ragnarthered" rather than "post by 337).
As you know, generating a JHipster app comes with a function that allows you to fetch a user by his login, not by his id. I tried creating the code necessary for these in Spring, but somehow it does not work. It doesn't even make the request, weirdly. I have also tapped in SecurityConfig and permitted all operations on the URL(for dev purposes only)

**Code in UserRepository**

```
User findUserById(Long id);
```

**Code in UserService**

```
public UserDTO findOne(Long id){
    User user = userRepository.findUserById(id);
    return userMapper.userToUserDTO(user);
}
```

**Code in UserResource**

```
@GetMapping("/user/:{id}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUser(@PathVariable Long id){
    log.debug("REST request to get User : {}", id);
    UserDTO userDTO = userService.findOne(id);
    return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(Optional.ofNullable(userDTO));
}
```

**Request in Angular Controller**

```
vm.getUser=getUser;

    getUser();
    function getUser(){
        $http({method:'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/'+vm.review.userId}).
            then(function(response){
                $scope.status = response.status;
                vm.user = user;
        }, function(response){
            $scope.status = response.status;
            vm.user = user;
        });
    }
```

Some help?

Comment: What's the server is answering you ? Does `userService.findOne(id);` works as intended or you were not been able to test it ?

Comment: The server says nothing. If I'm loading the page which contains the controller for the request, there is actually no request being made to the user service in the console. And I don't really get why. And if I'm trying to make a request using Postman, it says Not Found(status 404, error 'Not Found', message 'Not Found', path '/api/user/1'

Comment: It might have something to do with `/user/:{id}`, try mapping you method with `/user/{id}` instead.

Comment: Flipping hell, it worked, man. Thanks

Comment: I'll write a proper answer if anyone has a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The `GET` mapping you used for your endpoint is wrong. Instead of `/user/:{id}` it should be `/user/{id}`.